# Remove decimal from year value in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, error-handling

I currently have a 'Year Built' column in a df describing the date buildings were built, when I imported the csv file the years all have decimal places after them: 1920.0, 1985.0  . How to I go about changing them into a datetime format or just removing the decimal place?

```
df1['Year Built'].head()
```

```
0    1920.0
1    1985.0
2       NaN
3    1930.0
4    1985.0
Name: Year Built, dtype: float64
```

When I tried to use datetime...

```
df1['Year Built'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Year Built'])

# check
df1['Year Built'].unique()
```

```
array(['1970-01-01T00:00:00.000001920', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000001985',
                                 'NaT', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000001930',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000001986', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000001987',
       '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000001988', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000001990',
```

Answer (score 1):

Add parameter `format` by `%Y` for match `YYYY` and also `errors='coerce'` for convert not matched values to misisng values `NaT`:

```
df1['Year Built'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Year Built'], format='%Y', errors='coerce')

print (df1)
  Year Built
0 1920-01-01
1 1985-01-01
2        NaT
3 1930-01-01
4 1985-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change them from float to int (and later string if you wont be processing them as numbers)

```
df1['Year Built'] = df1['Year Built'].astype(int)
```

and here is the link for more details
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Lion Nadej Ahmed answer you can use the **dtype** parameter when you read in the data, specifying int to prevent the year from becoming a float.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use datetime

```
import datetime
df1['year_built'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['year_built'])
print(df1)
```